# Would flows execute before QCP script?

Tags: visual-workflow, cpq, quotelineitem, cpq-plugins

This might be a fairly simple question but not much available documentation around it. I have a flow on SBQQ__Quote__c object which is making some field updates on related quote lines. I also have a QCP script in place which updates quote line fields. I am wondering what is the order of execution here, will QCP execute after the flow has finished? Or does the QCP run first? What happens if the flow is set to run asynchronously? Will the QCP run in parallel in such a case? Any pointers/inputs much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you're not in the Quote Line Editor, the QCP is launched after Save, after the flow.
Technically, the flow updates the quote line record in the data base. This action triggers a CPQ re-calculation : information is then sent to CPQ servers that run all calculations (price rules & QCP) and insert the result back on the records.